# Does recursion implies divide and conquer?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Is the principle behind all recursive problems divide and conquer? Eg : Finding factorial , binary search ...

Moreover, How does divide and conquer paradigm work? , Why is it easier to find factorial through recursion?

Comment: (Intentional) recursion is basically a form of iteration.  It can be used for most tasks where iteration would be appropriate, is ideal for some, and significantly less than ideal for others.  An advantage of recursion over simple iteration is that it does a loop within a loop within a loop... out to an arbitrary level very simply and efficiently.  Sometimes this feature is very powerful.

Comment: Factorial is probably the worst example on which to teach recursion to students who are new to the concept. They never "get" it, thinking that it should be better than iterations, but it isn't superior in any way - it's just different.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight what could be the better problems to really understand the power of recursion and D&C.

Comment: @teja my personal favorites are "8 queens", "BST walk", and "recursive descent parsing".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does recursion implies divide and conquer?

No. Recursion implies induction: moving the problem to a smaller scope until it is solvable (base condition) and then applying incremental changes all the way back.

Divide and conquer means dividing the problem into two (or more) smaller problems that will be recursively solved.

> Why is it easier to find factorial through recursion?

It's not "easier". Some will argue that it's more intuitive only that intuition is not something that can be properly defined in math :) To me, it is more intuitive to solve factorial in the iterative way (while loop).

And since no answer will be complete without a code example, here's factorial in the recursive and iterative implementations (Python):

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else: 
        return n * fact(n-1)

def fact_iter(n):
    res = 1;
    while n > 0:
        res *= n
        n -= 1
    return res
```

Comment: Thanks for cleary explaining the concept. I am facing the diffuclty with understanding why time complexity of recursive/divide and conquer algorithms is better than the normal varients.Pls shed some light.Also suggest some readings for understading

Comment: @teja what is considered as "normal variants"? if it's "brute force" then calculate the big O for each solution and you'll find out that for some problem the brute-force solution will be exponential while divide and conquer will run in polynomial time. As for reading, there are so many resources but the most famous is http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Edition-Thomas-Cormen/dp/0262033844